# Eigenvectors in model analysis

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

Say I have a model with five ODEs. This is a model based on virus, host cells and immune response somewhat similar to the model in [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3066295/):

[image]

I want to know what I can learn about the system through eigenvectors. I know that from eigenvalues I can learn about the stability. But, what do eigenvectors tell about the system?

Say I have eigenvalue $D$ and the corresponding eigenvector, $V$ as follows.
[image]

What can be determined about the system using eigenvectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the eigenvalues and -vectors you are talking about, are obtained through a linearisation of the dynamics at a particular fixed point $\tilde{y}$.
The linearised differential equation would thus have the shape:
$$\dot{y}=A(y-\tilde{y}),$$
where $A$ is the matrix whose eigenvalues ($D_1$, $D_2$, …) and eigenvectors ($V_1$, $V_2$, …) you are looking at.
The solutions to such a differential equation are known to be of the form:

$$ \tilde{y} + c_1 e^{D_1 t} V_1 + c_2 e^{D_2 t} V_2 + …$$

where the $c_i$ are constants determined by the initial conditions.

As you already know, this tells you something about stability. For example, if all eigenvalues are negative¹, solutions in the vicinity of $\tilde{y}$ will converge to $\tilde{y}$. The eigenvectors tell you along which direction this happens, i.e., how the solutions converge to or diverge from $\tilde{y}$. Practically, almost all initial conditions have components corresponding to each eigenvector (i.e., $c_i ≠ 0\;∀i$) and thus the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue¹ dominates the dynamics, as the corresponding term grows fastest or shrinks slowest, respectively. This is most prominent, if your largest eigenvalue is much larger than the next one¹.

For example, if your largest eigenvalue $D_1$ is positive and real and all others are negative¹, you do not only know that $\tilde{y}$ is not a stable fixed point, but also that in which direction the instability is directed. More specifically you can state that for initial conditions in the vicinity of $\tilde{y}$ you will get a solution of the form $\tilde{y} + c_1 e^{D_1 t}V_1$. So, in your application, if an uninfected state is a fixed point (which is unstable in terms of your differential equations, but practically stable due to the fact that virus numbers are discrete), you can describe how it would initially react to an infection with a small number of viruses.

---

¹ in the real part

Comment: Thanks  for the reply. How do I determine what the largest eigen vector is? Is it the eigenvector that correspond to the largest absolute eigen value? If there are complex eigenvalues how is this found? If it is so then the above example, largest eigen vector would be `[-0.912,0.4101,-0.0003,0.0003,0.006]`. As this is a unstable steady state, how I can interpret this, for example when I say for a small perturbation the system move away from the steady state in the direction of `[-0.912,0.4101,-0.0003,0.0003,0.006]` what does it mean? Say the components in the ODE are A,B,C,D,E,

Comment: Say the components in the ODE are A,B,C,D,E, then does it mean if I move component A in the -0.912 direction and B in 0.4101 direction and C in -0.003 direction... the system would move away from the steady state?

Comment: @sam_rox:  *How do I determine what the largest eigen vector is? […]* – I edited to clarify.

Comment: *how I can interpret this?* – Lets denote $V_1 = (-0.912,0.4101,-0.0003,0.0003,0.006)$ and say your steady state is $\tilde{y}$. Then your behaviour in the vicinity of $\tilde{y}$ will quickly be dominated by $\tilde{y} + c_1 e^{D_1 t}V_1$, where $c_1$ is determined by your initial conditions and $D_1$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to your eigenvector. So yes, the system will move in the direction of $V_1$. This is irrespective of the exact perturbation in your initial condition: Almost all initial conditions move the system away from the steady state.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. When eigenvalues are negative when finding the largest eigenvalue, is it the largest **absolute** value that should be considered? Also, just to clarify on the direction that the system takes after small perturbation, if I set the initial conditions as the equilibrium point and run the model for some time, say t=100, then the system values at t=100, should be given by $\tilde{y} + c_1 e^{D_1 t}V_1$, is it?

Comment: Are these steady $C_i$'s found by taking the system to be at equilibrium at time 0? So that initial conditions would be $\tilde{y}$. But, then when finding $C_i$' should it be $\tilde{y} =C_1V_1+C_2V_2+....+C_5V_5$ is it? Why is there a $\tilde{y} $ in  front of $\tilde{y} + c_1 e^{D_1 t} V_1 + c_2 e^{D_2 t} V_2 + …$? I thought the solution to the system should be $ c_1 e^{D_1 t} V_1 + c_2 e^{D_2 t} V_2 + …$.

Comment: @sam_rox: *When eigenvalues are negative when finding the largest eigenvalue, is it the largest **absolute** value that should be considered?* – No, *largest* really means *largest.* If you have $0>D_1≫D_2$, the term corresponding to $D_2$ will go towards $0$ much faster, hence it will be negligible compared to the term corresponding to $D_1$. — *if I set the initial conditions as the equilibrium point […], […] values […] should be given by $ỹ + c_1 e^{D_1t}V_1$, is it?* – Yes, if your linearisation is valid for the entire trajectory. Also, you have to start **near** the equilibrium point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67632/discussion-between-wrzlprmft-and-sam-rox).